# How do I expand $(1+x)^{1/x}$ for small $x$?

Tags: calculus

The binomial expansion
$$(1+x)^{n} = 1 + nx + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^{2}+...$$
didn't work because of the $n$ term being undefined at $x=0$.

Taylor expansion doesn't work either since it too would depends on an undefined $1/x$ term.

How does one do it?

Comment: Take log, then expand $log(1+x)$, then go back to the original by using expansion of $e^x$. You will get a few first terms, I would not expect any nice formula.

Comment: $$(1+x)^\frac{1}{x}=e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln(1+x)}=e^{\frac{1}{x}(x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-...)}=e^{1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}-...}$$
$$=e\cdot\bigg(\big(-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}-...\big)+\frac{1}{2!}\big(-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}-...\big)^2+ \frac{1}{3!}(..)^3+ ...\bigg)$$

Comment: @Svyatoslav Or more promising,$$e\cdot e^{-x/2}\cdot e^{x^2/3}\cdots = e(1-x/2+\cdots)(1+x^2/3+\cdots)\cdots$$

Comment: @J.G. You are right: your approach is more concise and easier to handle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's consider the function
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\log(1+x)}{x} & x>-1, x\ne0 \\[6px]
1 & x=0
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ is everywhere differentiable and its Taylor expansion at 0 is
$$
f(x)=1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}-\frac{x^3}{4}+\dotsb
$$
Now we have $(1+x)^{1/x}=e^{f(x)}$ (with continuous extension at $x=0$), so we can apply the series for $e^x$.

Say we want to find the Taylor expansion up to degree $3$, for simplicity, so we need
$$
\exp\Bigl(1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}-\frac{x^3}{4}+o(x^3)\Bigr)
$$
and we get
$$
e\Bigl(1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}-\frac{x^3}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\Bigl(-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}-\frac{x^3}{4}\Bigr)^2+\frac{1}{6}\Bigl(-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}-\frac{x^3}{4}\Bigr)^3+o(x^3)\Bigr)
$$
and so
$$
e\Bigl(1-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{x^2}{3}-\frac{x^3}{4}+\frac{x^2}{8}-\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{x^3}{48}+o(x^3)\Bigr)
$$
and, eventually,
$$
(1+x)^{1/x}=e-\frac{ex}{2}+\frac{11ex^2}{24}-\frac{7ex^3}{16}+o(x^3)
$$

Comment: Looks promising but I don't see how you got the Taylor expansion $f(x)$ for $x=0$ since the derivatives still also depend on a $1/x$ term. Most importantly though, how did you get the expansion $$e^{f(x)} = e(f(x) + \frac{f(x)^{2}}{2})+...$$ Wouldn't it be just $$e^{f(x)} = 1 + f(x) +\frac{f(x)^{2}}{2} + ...$$? Where did the $e$ coefficient come from?

Comment: @MichaelVeidt There is no $1/x$ term in the derivative; the function $f$ is analytic over $(-1,1)$. Next, if you expand $e^{1+t}$ you get $ee^t$.

Comment: Ah, I see. You took the Taylor expansion for $log(1+x)$ and multiplied that by $1/x$. I also now see where the $e$ coefficient came from, thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Binomial expansion whilst taking $n=1/x$ looks fine to me (though not a power series representation). True, your series is technically not defined at $x=0$ but then neither is the function $(1+x)^{1/x}$, but they have a well defined limit.

By [Newton's generalized binomial theorem](https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/cgt_online/book/section03.01.html), for nonzero $x\in (-1,1)$, we have

$$(1+x)^{1/x}=1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}{2!}x^2+\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}x^3+...|_{n=1/x}\\
=1+1+\frac{(1-x)}{2!}+\frac{(1-x)(1-2x)}{3!}+...$$

Note that the limit of the LHS as $x\rightarrow 0$ is $e$, while the RHS (second line) evaluated at $x=0$ is a series expansion of $e$.

Comment: Using this approach, every Taylor coefficient is obtained as an infinite series, after expansion of the products. Only the first term ($e$) comes easily. Technically, you used the *generalized* binomial expansion.

Comment: But OP thought their approach is invalid due to not being defined at $x=0$, and I am simply pointing out that it is still valid. I don't think OP specifically asked for power series representation?

Comment: Yep, you are quite right. But one should show that the expansion (whatever it is) converges for small $x$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks, will add in $x\in (0,1)$

Comment: Why this range ? How do you know the radius of convergence ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Newton's generalized binomial theorem